# MySQL unsafe statment with update && join

Tags: mysql, unsafe

I work on e-commerce site with large number of vendors sending data to it (or reading notifications) and I need to keep time of last connection for each of them. Since update of vendor table showed as bad practice (very large number of updates with bad performance) I created memory table in which I store last connection time for each vendor. That time is than updated once or twice in a minute. For update I use this query:

> UPDATE vendors NATURAL JOIN tmp_vendors SET vendors.last_conn_time = tmp_vendors.last_conn_time

What I keep getting in mysqld.log is:

> [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave.

So is there a way to turn off this warning (only on current DB connection) or is there any better practice for this?

Comment: Can you try running sql similar to UPDATE vendors INNER JOIN tmp_vendors 
    ON vendors.id = tmp_vendors.id
    SET vendors.last_conn_time = tmp_vendors.last_conn_time

Comment: In case you have multiple entries for the same vendor in  tmp_vendors, run something similar to UPDATE vendors INNER JOIN (select max(last_conn_time) as last_conn_time, tmp_vendors.id from tmp_vendors group by tmp_vendors.id) A ON vendors.id = A.id SET vendors.last_conn_time = A.last_conn_time

Comment: To consider other solutions, how often are you updating the temporary table? Are you using InnoDB for vendors table?

Comment: @Andy there is only single entry for one vendor in memory table, he's ID is PK for table

Comment: @MarcusAdams - updates are random, it can be 0 or 10 times in minute, and yes InnoDB is for vendors table

Comment: @Bernard Have you tried queries I mentioned?

Comment: @Andy both of them result in same warning

Comment: @Bernard Can you please post your table defenitions

Answer (score 0):

If the slave server loses powers, the memory table will be blank, and this will cause replication issues. So, as long as you're updating a table from a memory table, you will probably get this warning.

Unfortunately, there's not currently a way to suppress logging of warning messages in MySQL.

If you provide more details, we may be able to come up with an alternative solution to how you're doing it now.

Comment: Well power loss can always happen, but for few months server up-time is 100% and I'll rather have faster update which occurs very often than getting worried about power loss which may or may not happen. Memory table is not replicated, it's in separate DB.

Comment: @Bernard, I think even if a replication issue occurs, the worst case scenario would be stale data. You won't have auto-increment issues with that query. Consider posting a separate question about the performance issues that occurred when trying to update the InnoDB table directly, as it seems doable. Also, consider offloading some of the reads to your replicated (read only) database.

Answer (score -2):

Is your memtable indexed on 'vendor id' or similar? It sounds like the update to 'vendors' is getting confused by which entry for 'last_conn_time' to use. Would it be rational to keep only one entry / vendor in the memtable using 'insert.. on duplicate key update last_conn_time...'?

Comment: Given the absence of clarifying information I had to make some guesses. Hence the format.